# Chrome Update broke generated pdf download in php webapp - service worker seems at fault, but why?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, service-worker

So we have a little php web app that, among other things, allows the colleagues to export all the info into a pdf and download it.

This was done with wkhtmltopdf and the PDF was previously immediately forced to download, as in the "Save As" dialog would pop up instead of trying to open it in the browser, etc.

Headers included:

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
header('Content-Type: application/download', false);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Now with the latest Chrome Update (71.0.3578.98) the PDF does not SEEM to be generated at all. It is not "force downloaded" or even shown in the browser, however via file->save as or the keyboard shortcut (ctrl+s) you can save it, so it is still generated, just not displayed in any way..

I noticed if I unregister the service worker on our page, it behaves as it had before the chrome update.

Ive tested this on a few colleagues computers, some with that newest version of Chrome, others before the update, and am 99.9% sure that is the culprit. What exactly made this change in behavior occur though, I am not sure.

Any idea how to get around this and have it "force" download again? Can I blacklist pdfs from the service worker somehow?

**EDIT**: Can also confirm this behavior from the following Chrome version:  72.0.3626.7 (Developer Build)

Answer (score 1):

Alright so this was kinda quick, and I'd generally just delete this, but I have a sneaking suspicion this might come up more often for others as soon as this Chrome update starts being applied in more places.

So this might not be a legitimate "fix" for this, but by adding a few lines to my serviceworkers fetch block I was able to exclude the URLs which generate PDFs and therefore the download was again offered up as normal.

i.e.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // Here you can use indexOf or a regex if you'd like  
  if ( event.request.url.indexOf( '/format/pdf/' ) !== -1 ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Yup, we already had a `ignore = /\/serviceWorker[.]js$/` regex that was used like `if (ignore.test(event.request.url)) return;` inside the fetch function to make sure serviceWorker.js is never cached. Just changing ignore to `/(\/serviceWorker[.]js|[.]pdf)$/` was the ticket for our pdf's. Oddly enough, embedded (`<object>`) pdfs still rendered fine through the service worker...